# Build two distros with one yocto image recipe

Tags: yocto

I am currently able to build one linux distro with grub bootloader using an image recipe. Is there a way to build two separate distros and combine them into a single image? Ideally, grub would give a choice of which one to boot from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something called "multiconfig" would would allow you to build two different distro configurations at the same time. The code to merge those images into one doesn't exist today though, multiconfig is still in comparative infancy.